# NullPointerException on navigate function - Jetpack Compose NavHostController

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt, android-jetpack-navigation

I implemented Google OneTap Authentication using FirebaseAuth on my Jetpack Compose application. The problem I face is that after I sign in successfully, if I close my application and start it again I get a NullPointerException caused by my `checkAuthState()` function which redirects the user to the profile page if it is already authenticated.

Error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.codrutursache.casey, PID: 28428
                                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                                        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1652)
                                                                                                        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1984)
                                                                                                        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate$default(NavController.kt:1979)
                                                                                                        at com.codrutursache.casey.presentation.MainActivity.navigateToProfileScreen(MainActivity.kt:78)
                                                                                                        at com.codrutursache.casey.presentation.MainActivity.checkAuthState(MainActivity.kt:74)
                                                                                                        at com.codrutursache.casey.presentation.MainActivity.access$checkAuthState(MainActivity.kt:33)
                                                                                                        at com.codrutursache.casey.presentation.MainActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:68)
                                                                                                        at com.codrutursache.casey.presentation.MainActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:42)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:428)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:252)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:251)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:195)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:119)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:118)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:110)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$2.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:158)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$2.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:157)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:157)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:142)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ActualJvm_jvmKt.invokeComposable(ActualJvm.jvm.kt:78)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3340)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3273)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:588)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:1013)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:520)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:142)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:133)
2024-01-08 18:13:08.263 28428-28428 AndroidRuntime          com.codrutursache.casey              E      at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1191)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.android.kt:133)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged(Wrapper.android.kt:183)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.kt:314)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.kt:192)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:140)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:133)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1266)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:21980)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3490)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3014)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2465)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9305)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1339)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1348)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:952)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:882)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1322)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
```

This is my MainActivity code which handles the auth check and instantiates the `navController`:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
@ExperimentalAnimationApi
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var navController: NavHostController
    private lateinit var authViewModel: AuthViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            navController = rememberNavController()
            authViewModel = hiltViewModel<AuthViewModel>()

            val isBottomBarVisible =
                rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

            CaseyTheme {
                isBottomBarVisible.value = when (currentRoute(navController)) {
                    Route.AuthRoute.route -> false
                    Route.ProfileRoute.route -> true
                    else -> true
                }
                Scaffold(
                    bottomBar = {
                        if (isBottomBarVisible.value)
                            BottomBar(navController = navController)
                    }
                ) { paddingValues ->
                    NavGraph(
                        navController = navController,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues)
                    )
                }
            }

            checkAuthState()
        }
    }

    private fun checkAuthState() {
        if (authViewModel.isUserAuthenticated) {
            navigateToProfileScreen()
        }
    }

    private fun navigateToProfileScreen() = navController.navigate("profile_screen")

}

@Composable
fun currentRoute(navController: NavController): String? {
    val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    return navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you pass the navController as a parameter to the `checkAuthState` function instead of using lateinit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't exactly tell where the error is coming from, as you are using a fairly atypical structure in your Activity. You can try to move the
`checkAuthState` function call into a `LaunchedEffect` like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        CaseyTheme {

            navController = rememberNavController()
            authViewModel = hiltViewModel<AuthViewModel>()
            val isBottomBarVisible = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

            isBottomBarVisible.value = when (currentRoute(navController)) {
                Route.AuthRoute.route -> false
                Route.ProfileRoute.route -> true
                else -> true
            }

            Scaffold(
                bottomBar = {
                    if (isBottomBarVisible.value)
                        BottomBar(navController = navController)
                }
            ) { paddingValues ->

                LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                    checkAuthState()
                }

                NavGraph(
                    navController = navController,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A typical Activity in Compose looks like this:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            CaseyTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    CaseyApp()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you place your root `Scaffold` into the `CaseyApp` Composable:

```
@Composable
CaseyApp() {
    navController = rememberNavController()
    //...

     Scaffold(
         //...
      ) { paddingValues ->

          LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
              checkAuthState()
          }

         //...
     }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. Thank you so much! Since you've mentioned that I use a fairly atypical structure in my Activity could you give me an example of how I can improve the current state of my code? Maybe some good practices and stuff like that.

Comment: I added an example of a typical Jetpack Compose Activity. If this answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as the accepted answer by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer :)

Comment: Your answer is checked now, thank you!